# Hellinger distance to find outliers. How to go from data to probability distribution?

Tags: probability, outliers, hellinger

One can find outliers in a data set if you fit that data in a probability distribution and see how well the data fits in the model (Normal data instances occur in high probability regions of a stochastic model, while anomalies occur in the low probability regions of the stochastic model.).
In this method you make an assumption of the data pattern because of the chosen probability distribution. (Method 1).

However when I read this paper a different method is shown (method 2):
Source: Detecting Cellular Fraud Using Adaptive Prototypes:
https://ocs.aaai.org/Papers/Workshops/1997/WS-97-07/WS97-07-002.pdf
Here they are using Hellinger distance to compare 2 probability distributions (based on 2 datasets, 1 active and 1 from the past).
What I don't understand is how you go from actual data to a probability distribution?

Please forgive any errors as I'm a beginner in statistics

Comment: Sure, you can turn pretty much any batch of numbers into a probability distribution. Case in point, the mean number of letters per word in Vicent's first crossvalidated post. Call that the Vincent_ave_0 distribution. it has an [empirical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function). You can compare it to, say, the empirical distribution of mean number of letters per words in Vicent's 101th post on cv.

Comment: And in method 1 you create the distribution once and than check whether your new data fits the probability distribution you've chosen. Method 2 creates a new distribution each time there is new data and compares it to an older version of the probability distribution by using Hellinger distance. Is that correct?

Comment: what are method 1 and method 2? Do they refer to something in the paper?

Comment: I didn't make that clear. I explained it in the starting post now